# is not assignable to parameter of type never

Tags: typescript

I have the following line of code:

```
if (!target.unit.subTypes.includes(effectAmount.multiplicator.subType)) continue
```

The line throws the error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'CreatureSubType | StructureSubType' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. Type 'CreatureSubType' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

`target.unit.subTypes` is defined as:

```
public subTypes: CreatureSubType[] | StructureSubType[]
```

whereas both `CreatureSubType` and `StructureSubType` are regular enums.

`multiplicator.subType` is therefore defined as:

```
subType?: CreatureSubType | StructureSubType
```

I dealt with the optional case before.

I don't understand why that error occurs. I also tried rebuilding this case a bit simpler [here](https://jsfiddle.net/r8vkc24e/8/) but it works without problem there. What am I missing?

EDIT:

Ok, I have managed to create a somewhat minimal example. Test class:

```
export class Foo {
  constructor(public subTypes: CreatureSubType[] | StructureSubType[]) {}
}
```

If I use this class like that:

```
const foo = new Foo([CreatureSubType.HUMAN])
foo.subTypes.push(3)
```

Then it complains about "Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.", meaning that subTypes somehow has a never type, even though it is clearly specified as `CreatureSubType[] | StructureSubType[]`, and I am even passing in one `CreatureSubType`.

Why is that?

EDIT 2:

The same thing happens, with arrays of basic types like `subTypes: number[] | boolean[]`. But it does not happen, if there are no arrays involved. `subTypes: number | boolean` does not loose its type and will not be resulting in type never.

Comment: While you say it's a `CreatureSubType[] | StructureSubType[]`, the error message implies that target.unit.subTypes is actually a `never[]`. Without seeing more code i'm not sure how that mismatch is happening, but perhaps you're creating an empty array literal without specifying a type, so typescript infers it to be `never[]`.

Comment: @NicholasTower: That cannot really be. Before, CreatureSubType and StructureSubType were one. I just split them and their type definitions apart into two. Since then, without changing any other code, that error appears. Hovering over target.unit.subTypes shows that it is indeed of type CreatureSubType[] | StructureSubType[]

Comment: Please provide a [mre]; otherwise it's hard to know how to advise specifically.  My *general* suggestion is to widen `CreatureSubType[] | StructureSubType[]` to `readonly (CreatureSubType | StructureSubType)[]` before using array methods, but without a [mre] I can't be sure (and wouldn't feel comfortable writing an answer).

Comment: @jcalz: Added a minimal example that reproduces the problem i have..

Comment: Sorry, by a [mre] I mean something self-contained that *others* can use to reproduce the problem.  If I put that code into [an IDE](https://tsplay.dev/WYRQ3w) I see errors unrelated to your problem, because neither my IDE nor I know what `CreatureSubType` or `StructureSubType` are.  If you replace them with `string`/`number` and that demonstrates your issue, could you actually show that code?

Comment: Note that it is not safe to `push()` a value into a union of arrays; if all you know about an array is that it *either* holds `number` elements *or* holds `string` elements but does not necessarily hold both, then you can't push a number onto it safely.  If you need to be able to do this then you want generics and not unions, maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nne8ew).  Does that meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, please [edit] with a clear self-contained [mre] that shows exactly the issue with it, when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE.